# How to handle DNS-lookup failure to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

(I'm quite new to Windows Azure development, so I hope I'm using the right terms.)

We have an Azure Worker Role that is supposed to fetch data stored in Blob Storage.
Somehow we occasionally get the following error message:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException: The server encountered an unknown failure: The remote name could not be resolved: 'XXX.blob.core.windows.net' ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'XXX.blob.core.windows.net'

This seems strange, since requests only a second before and/or after works as expected.

If I understand things correctly, the CloudBlob class has internal retry functionality. It seems that this is not considered as a "retryable" error. Is this perhaps handled by the Transient Error Handling Block (Topaz), or do we have to handle this specific error in some other way?

Comment: What version of Azure Storage Library are you using?

Comment: We're using version 1.7. (I know it's old but the current structure of the project makes it hard to replace with a newer version...)

Comment: Well, my first thought is that I believe the retry logic has been significantly improved in versions above 2.0. It might be a pain to change, but the pain might be worth it. There are some really big improvements in the new libraries beyond the retry stuff as well.

Comment: Yeah. I noticed this comment for the 'Topaz' NuGet package; "if you are using version 2.0 [...], it is recommended that you use the built-in retry policies". I've already brought up the need for upgrading the library with the team and they all agreed that it would a good idea to upgrade. Looks like we're in for some pain. :)